# PS file to PDF or image

Tags: c#, .net

I have requirement to create virtual printer which used to register my printer in the printer drive ,Whenever my printer invoked it should generate PDF file for respective page . I had created and invoked my printer functionality,here comes the problem,i could not find how to convert temp file(.PS) to PDF file or any image file.Please let me know if anyway I cld achieve this....

Thanks in advance,
Vinod

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a library that will convert from PS to PDF for you.  A quick Google shows that there are libraries available, but they may not be free.  It's up to you to go and look for yourself now to see if any suit your requirements.